# GROUP BY doesn't distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can't seem to understand why, but i'm trying this query :

```
SELECT called,caller,time,duration
FROM Calls
GROUP BY called,caller,time,duration
```

But that returns rows with same `called` value which is not i want.

Basically i'm trying to build a bigger query, just going step by step with that. 
i need a query to return latest entry for every `called` per `caller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want only distinct `called` values but all columns. If there are multiple `called` i take only the last (ordered by `time`):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT called,caller,time,duration,
      RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY called ORDER BY time DESC)
   FROM Calls
)
SELECT called,caller,time,duration
FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: @TimSchmetler Missed comma after `duration`.

Answer (score 0):

> i need a query to return latest entry for every called per caller

Try this instead:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
      called,
      caller,
      time,
      duration,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY caller
                        ORDER BY called DESC) rownum
    FROM Calls
)
SELECT
  called,
  caller,
  time,
  duration
FROM CTE 
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a096/2)

Comment: @eric.itzhak - Sorry, `PARTITION` was written incorrect. Fixed now. See my edit

Comment: @eric.itzhak - It was a missed semicolon after `duration`. See my edit.

Comment: @eric.itzhak , missed comma after `duration` .

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud this also is a working solution, i marked Tim's as more accurate to my case.

Comment: @eric.itzhak - You're welcome any time. It is alright. Doesn't matter whose answer is accepted, was it helpful? that is whats matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason be that you cant group by multiple categories, have alook at teh example below:

```
SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
 FROM table_name
 WHERE column_name operator value
 GROUP BY column_name
```

Have a look at this website for more examples on this 
[WEBSITE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: i must, otherwise i get a `Column 'Calls.caller' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` error